# Wrap text works in all browsers except IE

Tags: css, iframe, word-wrap

I have a widget on a page that calls another script for source. Like this:

```
<!-- Beginning of widget code. -->
<div id="xyz_widget" ></div>
<script id="bootstrap" type="text/javascript" src="<some location>/bootstrap.js?" charset="utf-8">
</script>
```

In bootstrap.js exists this iframe code:

```
<iframe style='background:transparent;overflow:hidden;border:0px;height:100%;width:100%' 
frameborder='0' border='0' marginwidth='0' marginheight='0' "width='100%' height='100%' 
allowTransparency='true'
src='"+buildBaseUrl (pUri)+"/widget/widget.jsp?"+pUri.query+"'>
</iframe>
```

My issue is that I am unable to wrap long text inside the frame. So 111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111 busts out of the frame width. I tried word-wrap:break-word but it does not help.

I should also mention that the issue exists only in IE. FF, Chrome, Safari all work ok.

Any help?

Comment: as a side note, you'd think that eventually Microsoft would notice that about half of all programming questions asked online end in some form of "works in all broswers except IE"

Comment: LOL! I am waiting for the day Microsoft deigns it fit to realize that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this css property [-ms-word-wrap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms531186%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), In the page that the `iframe` loads put a `div` like this

```
<div style="word-wrap:break-word;width:100%;left:0">
    ... //content on the page
</div>
```

Hope that helps,

Comment: I tried that already Eric (I mentioned that in my original post). It didn't work :(

Comment: I changed the iframe tag to this:

Comment: <iframe style='background:transparent;overflow:hidden;border:0px;height:100%;width:100%;wrap-word:break-word'> Didn't help at all

Comment: Do you have access to the page you loading in your iFrame?

Comment: Yup, I do     

For some reason I can't add comment to your previous enquiry.

Answer (score 0):

Please, try:

```
.wrapWords {
    width: 300px;
    white-space:      pre-wrap; /* css-3 */
    white-space: -moz-pre-wrap; /* Mozilla, since 1999 */
    white-space:     -pre-wrap; /* Opera 4-6 */
    white-space:   -o-pre-wrap; /* Opera 7 */

    word-wrap: break-word; /* Internet Explorer 5.5+ */
}
```